# how to remove rowheaders from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

right so this is my .csv file

```
,n,bubble sort,insertion sort,quick sort,tim sort
0,10,9.059906005859375e-06,5.0067901611328125e-06,1.9073486328125e-05,1.9073486328125e-06
1,50,0.0001659393310546875,8.487701416015625e-05,5.3882598876953125e-05,3.0994415283203125e-06
2,100,0.0006668567657470703,0.0003230571746826172,0.00011801719665527344,7.867813110351562e-06
3,500,0.028728008270263672,0.011162996292114258,0.0013577938079833984,6.008148193359375e-05
4,1000,0.11858582496643066,0.049070119857788086,0.0027892589569091797,0.000141143798828125
5,5000,2.022613048553467,0.8588027954101562,0.011118888854980469,0.0006251335144042969
```

and I was a bit confused with how could I remove the row headers from this line since its using DataFrame to get those row headers.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(timming)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Your question doesn't explain the issue you're having well. I verified that the CSV file you posted can easily and correctly be parsed into a dataframe using `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: Do you want something like that: `pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=1, header=None).drop(columns=0)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(timming , header=None)
```